# Serial near duplicate questions from one user

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

For future reference I was wondering how a series of near duplicate questions from a single user should be handled. At the moment I don't have the rep on SO to do anything but flag questions but the following is the sequence of questions that leads me to ask:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078996/why-is-there-this-c-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079616/c-compile-error

[why do I get the out of date message in visual c++ 2010 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078296/why-do-i-get-the-out-of-date-message-in-visual-c-2010-express)

In isolation while not stellar questions they are probably not worthy of flagging. However in combination they clearly all relate to the same piece of code / problem in general so I feel the OP should have left it as a single question and followed up on the various comments / answers made.

At the moment the series of questions seems to have left everyone including myself that tried to contribute confused as to the current state of the problem and what he has / hasn't tried.

Comment: The second should be flagged as a duplicate of the first. The third could also be marked as a duplicate, although i am not sure about that.

Comment: Confused is an understatement, going by the comments and answers

Comment: I did my best to clean it up a bit and make sure answers on the still open one make sense. It is a little difficult to figure out what he's actually hitting. I don't think I can figure out the other one.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully soon he soon works out the answer to his first question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079350/is-programming-worth-it and picks something else

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes new users who are also completely new to programming just aren't sure what to do. Flagging is definitely the remedy, use the 'other' reason and let us know what's going on. A little editorial love, when you can figure out the question enough to edit it also helps.

He seemed to believe that the same identical code snippet warranted a new question for each error he received while trying to build it.

I closed one, which was basically a duplicate of the first with the exception of the error changing, the other seems to be a totally different question, just equally basic.

I'm going to go see what I can do about cleaning up the first, and possibly merging some of the answers, however as you said he's got everyone a bit perplexed :)